# Any reason why a sql converted date is converted wrongly?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm using the following code:

```
sqlcom.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
                    + " WHERE CAST(myTime AS DATE) >= CAST(@mySTime AS DATE)"
                    + " AND CAST(myTime AS DATE) <= CAST(@myETime AS DATE)"
                    + "order by myTime ";

sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySTime", stime);
sqlcom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myETime", etime);
```

`stime` and `etime` are both `DateTime` columns. The following is an abbreviation of the code that sets them:

```
sTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(-1);

eTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(-1).AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);
```

Which for example leads to:

```
sTime = '2015-10-19 00:00:00';
eTime = '2015-10-19 23:59:59';
```

when displayed in the debugger (`stime` and `etime` have a few other options how they could be set that is why the sql is dynamically taking them in but in this current case the above holds true).

Now when I run the above SQL I get everything even from the current day!
BUT when I change `AS DATE` to `AS DATETIME` it works as intended that I just get the LAST day and nothing from today.

Now my question is: Is there any reason why the original sql/date comparison fails? (could it be because of that it is just the millisecond -1 that it rounds it up to the next day? OR is there any other reason there?)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: When working with continuous data, I'd almost always recommend using an inclusive start point and an *exclusive* end point, and using `<` for the endpoint comparison. It tends to be easier to compute the required endpoint *and* you don't have to consider the precision of your data type.

Comment: Also, `DateTime.Now.Date` is a far better way to get today's date without time, rather than risking that code such as `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day,...` which might be executing over midnight and so get an incorrect month/day combination

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point there. Was mostly something because of another case where I put this date together (with a fixed date,year,day)..copy & paste from that one to the datetime.now case^^' ). and good point about the endpoint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> eTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0).AddDays(-1).AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1);

- Why are you using `.AddDays(-1).AddDays(1)`. It seems useless.
- `.AddMilliseconds(-1)`

Your data type is **datetime**. **datetime** has an accuracy of 3ms with increments of .000, 003 or .007 seconds. 
Therefore, any of these 3 values minus 1 (ms) is always rounded back to the original value:

```
xxx.000 - .001 = .999 => rounded to .000
xxx.003 - .001 = .002 => rounded to .003    
xxx.007 - .001 = .006 => rounded to .007
```

This seems useless as well.

> Round up

`'2015-10-19 23:59:59'` won't be rounded but `'2015-10-19 23:59:59.999'` will be round up to `'2015-10-20 00:00:00.000'` because `999` is surrounded by `997` and `000`. `000` is the closest value.

> `<= 18-10-2015 23:59:59`

You will miss any time above `23:59:59.000` and below of equal to `23:59:59.997`

> CAST(myTime AS DATE)

This will most likely prevent the usage of index on myTime. It should not be used.

It is fine to stick to datetime although datetime2 would be a better choice. If you are looking for value on a specific day, you must look for value between DAY at 00:00:00 and the next day at 00:00:00.

You can find a lot of useful information about date comparison on most of the answer here, including my own anwser: [Why does my query search datetime not match?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108287/why-does-my-query-search-datetime-not-match/112956#112956)

Comment: Like mentioned its abbreviated how I put them together in case of a few specific parameters those are the commands that are used there. Thus I listed them as they will be executed in that case. So in essence what I'm reading from you it is so that what the debugger is displaying (2015-10-19 23:59:59  for eTime) is wrong?

Comment: when I look at your sample code, stime = etime - 1s but your reduced code should do -1ms. Based on your abbreviated code, etime should equal to stime

Comment: stime should have been 18-10-2015 00:00:00 while  etime should have been 18-10-2015 23:59:59  at least according to plan (ms I only took to get as good as any data as possible back then.....copy&pasted the basic idea from an old project and didnt think about < next day^^').

Comment: you should use >= DAY 1 at 0h because you know it is the begeging of the day and < DAY 2 at 0h because it is the begining and anytime before it belongs to DAY 1. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108287/why-does-my-query-search-datetime-not-match/112956#112956